# How to find the minimum of the list of the terms?

Tags: list, prolog, minimum

I have a list of terms as below

```
[t('L', 76), t('I', 73), t('V', 86), t('E', 69)]
```

I want to write a predicate in prolog so that it will return the term with minimum second value. i.e. from above list it should return `t('E', 69)`

Below is what I tried. But this is not working.

```
minChar(L, Min) :-
    setof(t(_, A), member(t(_, A), L), Li),
    Li = [Min|_].
```

Here is the output it gives for above input.

```
?- minChar([t('L', 76), t('I', 73), t('V', 86), t('E', 69)], Min).
Min = t(_G14650, 69) ;
Min = t(_G14672, 73) ;
Min = t(_G14683, 76) ;
Min = t(_G14661, 86).
```

Comment: Please explain *is not working*. Also a predicate name *must* be an atom, so `MinChar` is an invalid predicate name. An atom would start with a lower case letter. Variables start with upper case.

Comment: Sorry for the Typo. I have manually typed the code, hence the typo. Updated the post with correction.

Comment: @user114754: do you want to return the second value, or the entire term. (for the given example, should it return `69`, or `t('E',69)`)?

Comment: I see. It gave you what you asked for. You asked for an anonymous variable as the first argument. Just use a variable: `setof(t(C, A), member(t(C, A), L), Li)`. In this case, since the two arguments have the same ordering, it will give you the right order. Otherwise, you need to do something like what @Oskar answered.

Comment: Actually, just `msort(L, Li)` would work (again, assuming the first argument of `t/2` has the same ordering as the second, which it seems to in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lurker says, predicates can't start with a capital letter, so fix that first.

There are two basic problems here: first off all, the two underscores in your second line refers to different variables, so `setof/3` doesn't know that you want the same variable both in the template and in the `member/2` call.

Second, setof sorts the result (which is why you can extract the minimum like that), but the way you've constructed the template, it will sort it incorrectly. Sorting in swi-prolog uses the [standard order of terms definition](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder), and in your case, you're sorting compound terms of the type `t(A, B)`, where A is an atom and B is a number. This will sort it lexicographically first on A and then on B, which is not what you want, you want to sort on B.

The standard trick here when you want to sort things with a key that isn't identical to the term itself is to extract the key you want, bind it with the `(-)/2` functor, and then sort it. So, for your example, this should work:

```
minChar(L, Min) :- 
  setof(B-t(A, B), member(t(A, B), L), Li),
  Li = [_-Min|_].
```

Remember here that in Prolog, when you say `X - Y`, you're not actually doing any subtraction, even though it looks you are. You are simply binding X and Y together using the `(-)/2` functor. It only does subtraction if you specifically ask it to, but using some operator that forces arithmetic evaluation (such as `=:=`, `<`, `>` or `is`, for instance). This is why `1+1 = 2` is false in Prolog, because `=` is a unification operator, and doesn't do any arithmetic evaluation.

To be clear: you don't *have* to use `-` for this, you can use whatever functor you like. But it's traditional to use the minus functor for this kind of thing.

Edit: also, `setof/3` will backtrack over any free variables not found in the template, and since the two underscores don't refer to the same free variables, it will backtrack over every possible assignment for the second underscore, and then throw that result away and assign a new free variable for the first underscore. That's why you can backtrack over the result and get a bunch of anonymous variables that you don't know where they came from.

Comment: Excellent explanation..!   Thanks a bunch..! functor `(-)/2` was the key.

Comment: @user114754: well the specific functor doesn't really matter, you could have used any functor. As long as the element on which you wish to compare is **the first term**.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I Totally agree. any functor would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `setof` which runs in *O(n log n)* (at least), you can also write a `minChar` predicate yourself:

```
minChar([X],X) :-
    !.
minChar([t(_,V1)|T],t(A2,V2)) :-
    minChar(T,t(A2,V2)),
    V2 < V1,
    !.
minChar([X|_],X).
```

Or you could further boost performance, by using an accumulator:

```
minChar([X|T],Min) :-
    minChar(T,X,Min).

minChar([],X,X).
minChar([t(A2,V2)|T],t(_,V1),Min) :-
     V2 < V1,
     !,
     minChar(T,t(A2,V2),Min).
minChar([_|T],X,Min) :-
    minChar(T,X,Min).
```

The code works as follows: first you unify the list as `[X|T]`, (evidently there must be at least one items, otherwise there is no minimum). Now you take `X` as the *first minimum*. You iterate over the list, and at each time you compare `t(A2,V2)` (the new *head* of the list), with `t(A1,V1)` (the currently found minimum). If the second attribute `V2` is less than `V1`, we know we have found a new minimum, and we continue our search with that term. Otherwise, the quest is continued with the old *current minimum*. If we reach the end of the list, we simply return the *current minimum*.

Another performance hack, is placing the empty list case as the last one, and place the *the current minimum is the smallest* case first:

```
minChar([t(_,V2)|T],t(A1,V1),Min) :-
     V1 <= V2,
     !,
     minChar(T,t(A1,V1),Min).
minChar([X|T],_,Min) :-
    minChar(T,X,Min).
minChar([],X,X).
```

This because Prolog always first executes the predicates in the order defined. It will occur only once that you reach the *empty list* case (at the end of the list). And after a will, the odds of finding a smaller value will be reduced significantly.

Comment: It's true, doing a full sort is a bit overkill in general if you just want to find the minimum. In this case, prolog's sort is written in highly optimized C, so unless the lists are staggeringly huge, doing it that way will probably be faster. However, you're correct in the general case.

Comment: @Oskar: don't see this as an offensive answer (did +1 on your answer), only showing that there are other ways to calculate the minimum.

Comment: Very true, I totally agree with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are a beginner in Prolog, so try to think Prolog.

What is the minimum of a list ? An element of this list, and no other element of this list is smaller.
So you can write

```
my_min(L, Min) :-
    member(Min, L),
    \+((member(X, L), X < Min)).
```

One will say : "it's not efficient !". Yes, but I think it's a good way to learn Prolog.

You should adapt this code to your case.

**EDIT** I said **adapt** :

```
min_of_list(L, t(X,Y)) :-
    member(t(X, Y), L),
    \+((member(t(_, Z), L), Z < Y)).
```

Comment: First of all, it works in *O(n^2)* time complexity, but furthermore it is always a bit dangerous to use negation (especially if the variables are not bounded), and finally one needs to compare on the **second term**. I think by default, prolog first compares on the first term.

Comment: For compound terms (like t(X, Y)), Prolog first compares arity, then by name of functor, and then finally recursively on the arguments in order. So t(1, 2) comes before t(2, 1), which is not what the question asker wants. In addition, the `<` operator doesn't work on compound terms, you have to use `@<` to compare using the standard order of terms.

Comment: @CommuSoft : I agree with not bounded variables, but, one more time, user114754 is a beginner in Prolog, and it's a good to change his way of thinking in Prolog (hope I'm understable).

Comment: @joel76: yeah sure, did +1 btw. But in general, negation is a bit a dangerous tool, becaus it is not fully negation, it is finite failure...